# Searching in txt files. all files without a match

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, txt

I have a `list` containing paths to `.txt` files in a folder that I would like to search. I am looking for specific phrases different for each file. I would like to categorize them all so I search the known categories and display the file if there is a match. Unfortunately I have no idea how to print the files if there is no match.

I'd like to print files without match.

```
FList = [] #list which contains path to .txt files

#searching phrases
for i in Flist:
   with open(i) as txtfile:
      if 'word1' in txtfile.read():
         print("Category I")
    with open(i) as txtfile:
      if 'word2' in txtfile.read():
         print("Category II")
    with open(i) as txtfile:
      if 'word3' in txtfile.read():
         print("Category III") `
```

I'd try resolve problem with logical operators:

```
with open(i) as txtfile:
    if not(('word1') or ('word2') or ('word3')) in txtfile.read():
       print(i)
```

but in this case string which is searching is always the first one (In this example it's the `word1` )

I know that isn't the most efficient code but thats not a point of this.

Comment: What do you think the value of `(('word1') or ('word2') or ('word3'))` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... I would like to *categorize* them all so I search the known categories and *display the file* if there is a match ...

You can try something simple like below :

```
dmap = {
    "word1": "Category I",
    "word2": "Category II",
    "word3": "Category III",
    # ... add here more mappings 
}

out = {}

for fp in FList:
    categories = []
    with open(fp) as tf:
        data = tf.read()
        for word, cat in dmap.items():
            if word in data:
                categories.append(cat)

    out[fp] = categories if categories else "No Match"
```

The `out`*put* should be like this one :

```
{
    'tmp/file1.txt': 'No Match',
    'tmp/file2.txt': ['Category II'],
    'tmp/file3.txt': 'No Match',
    ...
    'tmp/file7.txt': 'No Match',
    'tmp/file8.txt': ['Category I', 'Category II', 'Category III'],
    'tmp/file9.txt': ['Category III']
}
```

You can then filter this dictionnary to return the filepaths with or without a match :

```
>>> [fp for (fp, m) in out.items() if m != "No Match"] # files with at least a match

>>> [fp for (fp, m) in out.items() if m == "No Match"] # files with no match
```

Comment: It seems to work, but I have a stupid problem. I can't display out. I mean print(out) then I see categories (but it;s very hard to read) but when I want to display each separate line (for and in out print(i)) then only filenames are displayed

Comment: Since `out` is a dictionnary, you need to unpack it. Try this : `for fp, m in out.items():
    print(f"{fp}: {m}")`. You can also add an `if` condition to make some filterings.

Answer (score 0):

If you check `word1 or word2 or word3`, it will always return the first one, i.e., `word1`.

Also, you have used `or` and not `and`. `or` returns `True` even if one condition is `True`. `and` returns `True` only if all conditions are `True`.

So, try this:

```py
with open(i) as txtfile:
    content = txtfile.read()
    if not(('word1' in content) and ('word2' in content) and ('word3' in content)) :
       print(i)
```

Comment: That won't work, the first `read()` will consume the entire file, the other 2 will return an empty string and thus not contain any word

Comment: Exactly, unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Then maybe storing it in a variable is the only choice I think.

Comment: You can fix it by storing the entire text of the file in a separate variable then use the same one all 3 times

Comment: Could you give me a little example of it? I can't see that solution

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the answer I posted.